# How can I set up Vue.js in my Laravel Project ?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, vue.js, laravel-5.4

I work with Laravel and I try to do something with Vue.js but I can't see it up.

First of all I install Node.js and npm. 
Now I'm trying to user 'npm run watch'. To see if my js code runs on my laravel project.

But, when I type 'npm run watch' in my cmd. It's like this:

[image]

What should I do ?

Thanks !

Comment: [This](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/595) might address your issue, but what version of laravel mix do you have? (`yarn info laravel-mix version` if you have yarn installed, `npm list laravel-mix` otherwise)

Comment: laravel-mix@0.5.16

Comment: I solve it thank you @ChrisForrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your version of Laravel Mix is out-of-date; there was a [bug](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/595) fixed in March 2017 that addressed this issue on newer versions of webpack.

You can update your version of Laravel Mix by either doing this:

```
npm uninstall laravel-mix && npm install --save-dev laravel-mix
```

or updating your `package.json` file to change the version for `laravel-mix`

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "laravel-mix": "^0.11.4",
    ...
}
...
```

After changing the version number, run `npm update`.